# Getting Error while transferring data from one fragment to another fragment in android using fragment

Tags: android, interface, fragment, communication

```
public class MistakeGridFragment extends Fragment {

private Set<String> mistakeSelected = new HashSet<>();
private ListView listView;
private  ITransfer  iTransfer;

public MistakeGridFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mistake_dialog, container, false);
    MistakeListHelper mistakeListHelper = new MistakeListHelper(getActivity());
    mistakeLists.addAll(mistakeListHelper.getAllMistakegrid());
    init(view);
    return view;
}

@TargetApi(23)
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        iTransfer = (ITransfer) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        iTransfer = (ITransfer) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void init(View view) {
    relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mistakegrid_mainly);
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    // adding number of column
    for (int i = 0; i < mistakeLists.size(); i++) {
        String listvalue = mistakeLists.get(i).getListTypeValue();
        String name = mistakeLists.get(i).getListTypeName();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<Double, String>>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<HashMap<Double, String>> myMap = gson.fromJson(listvalue, type);
        for (int j = 0; j < myMap.size(); j++) {
            HashMap<Double, String> hash = myMap.get(j);
            view = setTypeOfMistake(name, hash, j);
        }
        relativeLayout.addView(view);
    }
}

private View setTypeOfMistake(final String mistakeName, HashMap<Double, String> hashValue, int i) {
    optionsArraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    //main mistake grid layout here added column
    LayoutInflater layoutInflatermain = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View main = layoutInflatermain.inflate(R.layout.mistake_column_layout, null);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) main.findViewById(R.id.linaerlayout);

    //here added row layout for each column
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mistake_row_layout, null);
    TextView mistakeType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_tv);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    Set set = (Set) hashValue.entrySet();
    Iterator it = set.iterator();
    optionsArraylist.clear();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HashMap<Double, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        optionsArraylist.add((String) entry.getValue());
        hashMap.put((Double) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        mistakeHashArryList.add(hashMap);

    }

    mistakeType.setText(mistakeName + "");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, optionsArraylist);
    listView.setAdapter(adaptor);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           toggleSelection(optionsArraylist.get(position).toString(), view);
            //Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this,parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mistakeSelected.contains(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString())) {
                mistakeSelected.remove(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.md_blue_grey_400));
            } else {
                mistakeSelected.add(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.md_blue_grey_500));
            }
        }
    });

    linearLayout.addView(view);
    return linearLayout;
}

public boolean getMistake() {

    if (mistakeSelected.size() > 0) {

        iTransfer.getData(mistakeSelected);
        return true;
    } else {
        new MyUtils(getActivity()).setMessageShort("Please selected any one mistake");
    }
    return false;
}

public interface ITransfer {
  public  void getData(Set<String> strings);
}

public class MistakeReasonFragment extends Fragment implements MistakeGridFragment.ITransfer {
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private LinearLayout addMistake_row;
    public MistakeReasonFragment() {
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mistake_reason_layout, container, false);
        init(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
        addMistake_row = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linaerl_row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void getData(Set<String> strings) {
        Log.v("value size ", strings.size() + " ");
    }

}
```

**LogCat:**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.root.ui.activity.QueActivity cannot be cast to com.tapasya.root.tapasya.ui.fragment.MistakeGridFragment$ITransfer
>   10-27 11:44:54.811 30409-30409/com.tapasya.root.tapasya W/System.err:
>   at com.android.root.ui.fragment.MistakeGridFragment.onAttach(MistakeGridFragment.java:70)
>   10-27 11:44:54.811 30409-30409/com.android.root W/System.err:
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1043)
>   10-27 11:44:54.811 30409-30409/com.android.root W/System.err:
>   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:838)
>   10-27 11:44:54.811 30409-30409/com.android.root W/System.err:
>   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:861)

Comment: pass context instead of activity

Comment: I have tried  but haven't got any solution

Comment: Forget everything use Eventbus to communicate between fragments and activities. Your life will become much easier. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: thanks for your solution I have tried it actually I am using view pager inside dialog fragment and there two fragment is initialize , i have try to used interface to communication between them and  also event-bus but i got problem with these it create view again and again whenever button is click

Answer (score 0):

Since, the context instance in onAttach() is the instance of the container activity for the fragment, make sure that the container activity has implemented the ITransfer callback, otherwise you cannot cast the instance of the context object in onAttach() to the ITransfer reference variable.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass data from one fragment to another  I have also used setArgument() method